# File uploads simply do not work - what could be wrong server side?

Tags: php, file-upload

This has been grinding my gears for at least a week now.

I have a site which has a crucial function - the upload component. Without it, the site is completely useless.

Now, lots of users have problems uploading files. This is why I implemented a log system that keeps track of what happens when the file is on the server.

Problem is, only a minority of problems happen when the file is on the server, the problems happen client side.

For example, when I tried SWFUpload the errors where 'I/O Error'. When I changed to Uploadify I get 'HTTP Error'. I am trying to get a more detailed error description as I type this.

I am starting to think its not the client or the upload software, but the server. What could be wrong? The following directives for PHP are set:

```
upload_max_filesize 200M
post_max_size 200M
memory_limit 256M
max_execution_time 4200
max_input_time 4200
```

I simply have no clue why file uploads are failing. They **should not** fail. I would really appreciate any answers as why the uploads could be failing.

Thank you.

Comment: As VirtuosiMedia asks are you setting the form type correctly? Can you replicate the problem yourself? I am unsure but does it happen for ALL uploads or only some? Try writing the $_FILES array to a log file somewhere everytime a file gets uploaded and fails, it usually contains a little more information.

Comment: Are you using PHP sessions? If I recall correctly, upload plugins like PHP upload might need to pass the PHP session id since otherwise their requests are not treated as being logged in.

Comment: Not always, for example, on the production server, a user has uploaded the exact same file twice. Once it failed, once it didn't.

I am passing the session id, which makes me think that maybe the session expires during the file upload. I'll check this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using enctype="multipart/form-data" as an attribute in your HTML form element?

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: It's an an attempt to eliminate a simple possibility. I overlooked it once and spent about 3 hours trying to debug my file uploads. Needless to say, I felt a little foolish that I forgot about setting this attribute.

Comment: Its a flash uploader, I would think it does that automatically. But I will check.